# How to reboot Ubuntu in Recovery Mode from SSH terminal shell?

Tags: ubuntu, system-recovery

I have Ubuntu 12.04 Virtual Machine running in cloud and the only way I can connect to it, is via SSH using Putty. If I want to boot Ubuntu in recovery mode, is it possible to create some kind of script and push over SSH to reboot Ubuntu Virtual Machine in recovery mode?

Comment: If you only have access to the VM via `ssh`, you will not be able to access it once it's in recovery mode. Is this what you want?

Comment: I think you are right. looks like there is no solution or trick to get the way I want.

Comment: I found this link but it still needed machine access to start ssh first before connecting it: http://askubuntu.com/questions/22013/how-to-enable-ssh-server-in-recovery-mode

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you think you need to be booted into recovery mode?  Couldn't you just adjust the system so it boots a livecd, or mount the virtual disk from another instance?

Comment: who do you host in the cloud with? Many providers have a recovery mode.

Comment: You can not do that. You need a console provided by your provider. If ssh is started on the system, it means the system already booted.

Comment: @Zoredache thanks dude, i've kicked the door of my boss while holding a self-burned ubuntu cd in my hand and said "stop all clusters and put thousands of active users offline, i will boot with this". he loved the idea but somehow, i am unemployed right now.

Comment: @eyurdakul, not sure what you are talking about. Either you miss-understood my comment, or I had miss-understood the question.  The way I read this question is that the OP had a cloud hosted VM that was broken and they needed to repair it.  My suggestion, to boot up another VM with recovery tools and access the storage of the broken VM, seems perfectly reasonable to me.  I have no idea how you think this equates to stopping all clusters and putting thousands of users offline.  The only thing that would be offline, was the apparently broken VM.

Answer (score 1):

try `shutdown now`

This will set the system into maintenance state/single-user mode. Unfortunately, this might also sever your connection.

Comment: Just a shot in the dark but I think you can add networking and ssh to your boot runlevel(think it's 1) and then do a telinit 1 or as mentioned shutdown now.